# Compute efficiently Hessian matrices in JAX

Tags: jax

In JAX's Quickstart tutorial I found that the Hessian matrix can be computed efficiently for a differentiable function `fun` using the following lines of code:

```
from jax import jacfwd, jacrev

def hessian(fun):
  return jit(jacfwd(jacrev(fun)))
```

However, one can compute the Hessian also by computing the following:

```
def hessian(fun):
  return jit(jacrev(jacfwd(fun)))

def hessian(fun):
  return jit(jacfwd(jacfwd(fun)))

def hessian(fun):
  return jit(jacrev(jacrev(fun)))
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit
from jax import jacfwd, jacrev

def comp_hessian():

    x = jnp.arange(1.0, 4.0)

    def sum_logistics(x):
        return jnp.sum(1.0 / (1.0 + jnp.exp(-x)))

    def hessian_1(fun):
        return jit(jacfwd(jacrev(fun)))

    def hessian_2(fun):
        return jit(jacrev(jacfwd(fun)))

    def hessian_3(fun):
        return jit(jacrev(jacrev(fun)))

    def hessian_4(fun):
        return jit(jacfwd(jacfwd(fun)))

    hessian_fn = hessian_1(sum_logistics)
    print(hessian_fn(x))

    hessian_fn = hessian_2(sum_logistics)
    print(hessian_fn(x))

    hessian_fn = hessian_3(sum_logistics)
    print(hessian_fn(x))

    hessian_fn = hessian_4(sum_logistics)
    print(hessian_fn(x))


def main():
    comp_hessian()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would like to know which approach is best to use and when? I also would like to know if it is possible to use `grad()` to compute the Hessian? And how does `grad()` differ from `jacfwd` and `jacrev`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is within the JAX documentation; see for example this section: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html#jacobians-and-hessians-using-jacfwd-and-jacrev

To quote its discussion of `jacrev` and `jacfwd`:

> These two functions compute the same values (up to machine numerics), but differ in their implementation: `jacfwd` uses forward-mode automatic differentiation, which is more efficient for “tall” Jacobian matrices, while `jacrev` uses reverse-mode, which is more efficient for “wide” Jacobian matrices. For matrices that are near-square, `jacfwd` probably has an edge over `jacrev`.

and further down,

> To implement hessian, we could have used `jacfwd(jacrev(f))` or `jacrev(jacfwd(f))` or any other composition of the two. But forward-over-reverse is typically the most efficient. That’s because in the inner Jacobian computation we’re often differentiating a function wide Jacobian (maybe like a loss function *:ℝⁿ→ℝ*), while in the outer Jacobian computation we’re differentiating a function with a square Jacobian (since *∇:ℝⁿ→ℝⁿ*), which is where forward-mode wins out.

Since your function looks like *:ℝⁿ→ℝ*, then `jit(jacfwd(jacrev(fun)))` is likely the most efficient approach.

As for why you can't implement a hessian with `grad`, this is because `grad` is only designed for derivatives of functions with scalar outputs. A hessian by definition is a composition of vector-valued jacobians, not a composition of scalar gradients.